# How to pass through multiple hyperlink attributes to a modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a hyperlink element to my modal, which updates based on the button clicked. Taking into consideration that I have more than 20 buttons, which are grouped into about 4 categories. Main question is, which is the best way to add a JS to my project for best management of my links?

I have tried using jQuery to replace() the button element but the change to the button element remains making it way complicated for the many links I have to deal with.

My Ideal solution would be having to pass through the buttons attribute, like the 'id', to my modal then have JS handle the links via the 'id' passed. For better management of the links, is this a good idea? If so, how might I achieve this? thanks in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <!-- Bootstrap 4.2.1 CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--elements with example links that i want to pass through start-->
  <a href="https://flyclipart.com/thumb2/blue-copyright-663972.png" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
          download 1
        </a>
  <a href="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/copyright-symbol-design_24908-22532.jpg" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
          download 2
        </a>
  <a href="https://icon-library.com/images/2018/556208_copyright-symbol-copyright-transparent-png.png" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
          download 3
        </a>
  <!--elements with example links that I want to pass through end-->

  <div href="" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">The file</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div>
            <label class="col-form-label">Description</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                  Close
                </button>

          <!--link that I would like to update via pass-thrugh for download-->
          <a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" download>Download</a
                >
                <!--link that I would like to update via pass-thrugh for download-->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <!--JQuery 3.6.0-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That all sounds fine, but your question is too broad. You need to make an attempt and ask about it, not just ask us for a solution. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I could totally be missing it, but I'm not seeing any links in this code.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. I have updated the code with the specific points of question and link examples.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-why-use-html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/modal/#events